# django-rest-framework custom user model login failed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django custom usermodel with restframework , after registering successfully I am unable to login for normal users.I am able to login via the initial superuser but if I create new superuser ,they are registered successfully but gives error while logging in as when trying with a normal user.

Error

```
Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
```

For few profiles I also observed following error in admin panel.

```
invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_login=now,
            date_time_onboarded=now,
            **extra_fields

        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
        return user


class AppOnboarding(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_time_onboarded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import AppOnboarding


class AppOnboardingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppOnboarding
        fields = ['email', 'product_name', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        app_onboard = AppOnboarding(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            product_name=self.validated_data['product_name']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        app_onboard.set_password(password)
        app_onboard.save()

    def save(self):
        app_onboard = AppOnboarding(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            product_name=self.validated_data['product_name']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']

        app_onboard.set_password(password)
        app_onboard.save()
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views



router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('app', views.AppOnboardingView)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status, viewsets

from .serializers import AppOnboardingSerializer
from .models import AppOnboarding




class AppOnboardingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = AppOnboarding.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppOnboardingSerializer
```

***settings.py**

```py
"""
Django settings for nrn project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

# , EMAIL_HOST_USER   , EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
from .email_info import EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'mz)6t6hfo*44sz*g)u&2o5!9p9azk!lwuju=*0lp_-c5)m-hj4'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'send',
    'apponboarding'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nrn.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nrn.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


EMAIL_HOST = EMAIL_HOST

EMAIL_PORT = EMAIL_PORT


EMAIL_USE_TLS = False

EMAIL_USE_SSL = False

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apponboarding.AppOnboarding'

# REST_FRAMEWORK = {
#     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
#         'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
#     ],
# }

# AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
#     'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
#     'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
# )
```

- Tried all the solutions on stackoverflow for similar problem but still it not working.
- Any help is highly apppreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your settings you have to mention your custom auth user model if you defined a custom user.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_custom_account.User'
```

For permissions you can add the following code to AppOnboarding

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is already there at the bottom most line in settings.py

Comment: both your create user and create super user doing same job?

Comment: is_staff=is_staff change to is_staff=True, also change similar superuser similarly and see

Comment: Done but it has no effect

Comment: is_staff in your AppOnboarding model, default is false, change to true

Comment: but when I login as  new users, it  does not have access to anything

Comment: Is it possible to give default view permissions of meta data to users ?

Comment: getting errors while makemigrations, ```ERRORS:
<class 'apponboarding.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'is_staff', which does not refer to a Field.```